# javascript regular expression return splited results

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm doing regular expression in office app for outlook. And the mail body will be something like:

```
Hello, I have the following path need to be translated. Can you help me with that?
\\test1
\\test2
\\test3
\\test4
Thanks.
```

And in the code I use getRegExMatches() to get the matched pattern.
regular expression:

```
<Rule xsi:type="ItemHasRegularExpressionMatch" PropertyName="BodyAsHTML" RegExName="test" RegExValue='file://[^"]*'/>
```

code:

```
matches=Office.context.mailbox.item.getRegExMatches().test;
```

And the matches is an array with the matched patterns:

```
[file://\\test1,file:///\\test2,file://\\test3,file:///\\test4];
```

But I want to return the result like:

```
[\\test1,\\test2,\\test3,\\test4]
```

Can regular expression do anything to split the result? Or is there any easy implementation to get the results to get rid of the file://or file:///. Although it's possible to iterate through the array to get the result, I'm wondering whether there's a better solution.

Comment: use a replace function. One to get rid of the `file:` and another to get rid of `/`

Comment: I don't understand very well your question. Are you asking for a regExp and using that pattern save its result in an array??

Comment: Could you add an example and the regex you are using?

Comment: Sorry that my question is not clear enough. I've changed the question and I have two questions. One is that can the regular expression in javascript not only get the string that match the pattern, but also return the result with the desired format. If not then the second question is how to format the strings in an array in javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have your array, you can use a regular expression to get what comes after `//`

```
var files = matches.map(function(f) { return f.match(/\/\/(.*)/)[1]; })
```

Or if it will always start with `file://` you can use substring:

```
var files = matches.map(function(f) { return f.substring('file://'.length); })
```

Comment: The second solution seems elegant, but the result will not always start with file://. It could be file:///. And I cannot use the regular expression to get what comes after // as there would be situation that have multiple //////, I just want the last //.

Comment: Well you can try `map(function(f) { return f.match(/\/+(.*)/)[1]; })`to have everything after any numbers of `/`. But I am not familiar with these ItemHasRegularExpressionMatch things, maybe you can have a better regexp right in your xml.